# What does useNewURLParser and userCreateIndex in mongoose.connect() do?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently new to MongoDB and NodeJS and I would like to know what the options useNewURLParser and useCreateIndex do.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager-api",
{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
})
```

Comment: See the doc with all the details: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MongoDB has two connection string formats.
The old format is now deprecated and uses an old URL format. There are `mongodb+srv://` URLs, and simple `mongodb://` URLs. If you are using the new format (you probably are by default), the new URL parser drops support for the old style urls.

`useCreateIndex`: Again previously MongoDB used an `ensureIndex` function call to ensure that Indexes exist and, if they didn't, to create one.
This too was deprecated in favour of `createIndex`. the `useCreateIndex` option ensures that you are using the new function calls.

Reference:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html

Comment: Note that as of 6.0 these are no longer supported on Mongoose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68962378/2282634

Answer (score 1):

```js
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
  .then(()=> {
    console.log(`Connected.........`);
  })
  .catch((err)=> {
    console.log(`Not connected....${err}`);
  });
```