# MongoParseError: options useCreateIndex, useFindAndModify are not supported

Tags: mongodb

I tried to run it and it said an error like the title. and
this is my code:

```
const URI = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

mongoose.connect(URI, {
   useCreateIndex: true, 
   useFindAndModify: false, 
   useNewUrlParser: true, 
   useUnifiedTopology: true 
}, err => {
   if(err) throw err;
   console.log('Connected to MongoDB!!!')
})
```

I set the MONGODB_URL in .env :

```
MONGODB_URL = mongodb+srv://username:<password>@cluster0.accdl.mongodb.net/website?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Check the docs for the version of Mongoose you are using, it should list the supported options.

Comment: if I'm not wrong, the version of mongoose you're talking about is the same as the version of mongoose that I install using npm I mongoose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Option "useFindAndModify" is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68915722/option-usefindandmodify-is-not-supported)

Answer (score 212, accepted):

From the Mongoose 6.0 [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options):

> useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, useFindAndModify, and useCreateIndex are no longer supported options. Mongoose 6 always behaves as if useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, and useCreateIndex are true, and useFindAndModify is false. Please remove these options from your code.

Comment: Are these options totally removed or replace with other code??

Comment: This answer from @Joe should be the accepted answer, since it report the documentation. A merge between this and the already accepted answer could be the best answer.

Comment: This is the winning answer if you're coming from 4.x/5.x ➡️ 6.x. You also need to change the deprecated `update`, `remove`, and `count` methods to the new ones.

Answer (score 41):

Same problem was with me but if you remove useCreateIndex, useFindAndModify it will solve the problem just write :

```
const URI = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

mongoose.connect(URI, {

useNewUrlParser: true, 

useUnifiedTopology: true 

}, err => {
if(err) throw err;
console.log('Connected to MongoDB!!!')
});
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 29):

### No More Deprecation Warning Options

`useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology`, `useFindAndModify`, and `useCreateIndex` are no longer supported options. Mongoose 6 always behaves as if `useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology`, and `useCreateIndex` are true, and `useFindAndModify` is false. Please remove these options from your code.

src --> https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options

```
// No longer necessary:
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
  useNewUrlParser: true, // <-- no longer necessary
  useUnifiedTopology: true // <-- no longer necessary
});
```

Answer (score 12):

I have the same issue.
Instaead

```
mongoose.connect(URI, {
   useCreatendex: true, 
   useFindAndModify: false, 
   useNewUrlParser: true, 
   useUnifiedTopology: true 
}, err => {
   if(err) throw err;
   console.log('Connected to MongoDB!!!')
})
```

try this:

```
mongoose.connect(URI,
    err => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('connected to MongoDB')
    });
```

Answer (score 10):

**The error is because of the new version of the mongoose i.e version 6.0.6.**

As the documentation says:

> No More Deprecation Warning Options
>
> `useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology`, `useFindAndModify`, and `useCreateIndex` are no longer supported options. Mongoose 6 always behaves as if `useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology`, and `useCreateIndex` are true, and `useFindAndModify` is false. Please remove these options from your code.

Also, there are some major changes in the new version.

For more info visit https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    
    const db = process.env.MONGOURI;
    
    const connectDB = async () => {
      try {
        console.log(db);
        await mongoose.connect(`${db}`, {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
        console.log('MongoDB connected');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        process.exit(1);
      }
    };
    
    
    export default connectDB;
```

Answer (score 9):

[image]

When I commented useNewUrlParser and useCreateIndex it worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 7):

remove **usecreateindex**, **usefindandmodify** options

```
const URI = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

mongoose.connect(URI, {
   useNewUrlParser: true, 
   useUnifiedTopology: true 
}, err => {
   if(err) throw err;
   console.log('Connected to MongoDB!!!')
})
```

Answer (score 7):

in new mongodb version you dont't have to use those:
useCreateIndex: true,
useFindAndModify: false,
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true

Comment: please explain your answer is useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true also optional ?

Answer (score 5):

Options `useCreateIndex`, `useFindAndModify` are not supported in version v6

```
try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    console.log("Connect successfully!");
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Connect Failure!", error.message);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Mongoose.connect(
    DB_URL,
    async(err)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("conncted to db")
    }
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the post to include an explanation of how the code solves the problem in the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
const URI = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

mongoose.connect(URI, {
   //useCreatendex: true, 
   //useFindAndModify: false, 
   useNewUrlParser: true, 
   useUnifiedTopology: true 
}, err => {
   if(err) throw err;
   console.log('Connected to MongoDB!!!')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

//this is working for me at date/version  (08-2021

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var url = "mongodb+srv://username:<password>@cluster0.accdl.mongodb.net/website? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Database created!");
        db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this to check your database connection:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const url = ... /* path of your db */;

//to connect or create our database
mongoose.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology : true, useNewUrlParser : true , }).then(() => {
   console.log("Connection successfull");
}).catch((e) => console.log("No connection"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology`, `useFindAndModify`, and `useCreateIndex` are no longer supported options.

basically, just remove that object and you'll be fine:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
const URI = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
mongoose.connect(URI, { useUnifiedTopology: true } 
);

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
} )
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. Just remove the "useCreateIndex: true" and it will work but make sure the mongoDB service is running on your local machine in the first place ~ brew services start mongodb-community@5.0 :)
#HappyCoding

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connect(URL,{
    }).then(()=>{
     console.log('database connected')
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log('database not connected',err)
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same thing, all i did was to just omit both (useFindAndModify: false) and (useCreateIndex), the reason being that my mongoose version never supported any of this..

Sure this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `asPromise()` Method for Connections
Mongoose connections are no longer thenable. This means that
`await mongoose.createConnection(uri)` no longer waits for Mongoose to connect.
Use `mongoose.createConnection(uri).asPromise()` instead.

// **The below no longer works in Mongoose 6**

```
await mongoose.createConnection(uri);
```

**// Do this instead**

```
 await mongoose.createConnection(uri).asPromise();
```

Answer (score 0):

const ConnectDB = async ()=>{
try{
const con= await mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://MahmoudReda:01102306392@cluster0.eqhn13z.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",{
useUnifiedTopology:true,
// useNewUrlParser:true,
// useCreateIndex:true
})
console.log("the connection is stable");
}
catch(error)
{
console.log(error.message)
process.exit(1);
}
}

this code is working well  useNewUrlParser and useCreateIndex not supported

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Mongoose Setup */
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6001;
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false); // answer
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Port:${PORT}`));
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

Answer (score 0):

the latest version of Mongoose does not support callback functions. so I uninstalled it and installed the previous version, which worked for me.

1. npm uninstall mongoose
2. npm install mongoose@6.10.0

- server.js - In your server.js file, you can connect to your MongoDB database using Mongoose with the following code:

  `mongoose.connect(URL,{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true } ) .then(() => console.log('Connected Successfully')) .catch((err) => { console.error(err); });`

Answer (score -1):

October 27th 2021
Without a try catch it won't work. I am just posting this to keep everyone up to date with mongo connections.

```
    const uri = process.env.ATLAS_CONNECTION;
    mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: 
    true });

    const connection = mongoose.connection;


    try{
    connection.once('open', () => {
        console.log("MongoDB database connection established 
     successfully");
    })
    } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    }

   function close_connection() {
    connection.close();
   }
```

[Connection Established](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QskV.png)

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same error the new mongoose version does already have these options by default for you so all you need to do is to remove these options and it will work perfectly.

Comment: How is this providing more new information than the already existing, highly voted answers?