# trying to connect mongoDB to my web app but it shows following error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Error:

> C:\Users\Bpc\Desktop\devcamper_api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:281
> throw new error_1.MongoParseError(`${optionWord} ${Array.from(unsupportedOptions).join(', ')} ${isOrAre} not supported`);
> ^

> MongoParseError: options usecreateindex, usefindandmodify are not supported
> at Object.parseOptions (C:\Users\Bpc\Desktop\devcamper_api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:281:15)
> at new MongoClient (C:\Users\Bpc\Desktop\devcamper_api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:62:46)
> at C:\Users\Bpc\Desktop\devcamper_api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:781:16
> at new Promise ()
> at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Bpc\Desktop\devcamper_api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:778:19)
> at C:\Users\Bpc\Desktop\devcamper_api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:330:10
> at C:\Users\Bpc\Desktop\devcamper_api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
> at new Promise ()
> at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Bpc\Desktop\devcamper_api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
> at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Bpc\Desktop\devcamper_api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1151:10)

and this is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDB = async () => {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,
        {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });
    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the response is clear in the log ` options usecreateindex, usefindandmodify are not supported`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems to be the same as:
[MongoParseError: options useCreateIndex, useFindAndModify are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958221/mongoparseerror-options-usecreateindex-usefindandmodify-are-not-supported)

> From the Mongoose 6.0 docs:
>
> > useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, useFindAndModify, and useCreateIndex >>are no longer supported options. Mongoose 6 always behaves as if >>useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, and useCreateIndex are true, and >>useFindAndModify is false. Please remove these options from your code.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68962378/7860331

Answer (score 3):

```js
const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, {});
```

This worked for me