# nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... MongoParseError

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Error:
[nodemon] starting `node backend/server.js`
Server started on PORT: 4000 i DEVELOPMENT mode.
D:\shop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:289
throw new error_1.MongoParseError(`${optionWord} ${Array.from(unsupportedOptions).join(', ')} ${isOrAre} not supported`);
^

MongoParseError: option usecreateindex is not supported
at parseOptions (D:\shop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:289:15)
at new MongoClient (D:\shop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:62:63)
at D:\shop\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:784:16
at new Promise ()
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\shop\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:781:19)
at D:\shop\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:341:10
at D:\shop\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
at new Promise ()
at promiseOrCallback (D:\shop\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (D:\shop\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1141:10)

Node.js v17.4.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

My code:

````
const connectDatabase = () => {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_LOCAL_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
    }).then(con => {
        console.log(`MongoDB Database connected with HOST: ${con.connection.host}`)
    })
}

module.exports = connectDatabase```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958221/mongoparseerror-options-usecreateindex-usefindandmodify-are-not-supported

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoParseError: options useCreateIndex, useFindAndModify are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958221/mongoparseerror-options-usecreateindex-usefindandmodify-are-not-supported)