# I installed mongodb and I want to connect it to next and I got error 500

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, nosql

[This is the error on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWCKP.png)
[This is my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Yagp.png)

this my address mongo :

```
MONGODB_URI= mongodb://localhost:27017/sinema
```

this page util/mongodb.js
`

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error("Your mongodb uri is not defined!");
}
let cached = global.mongoose;
if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null };
}
export async function connectToDatabase() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn;
  }
  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      bufferCommands:false,
      bufferMaxWntries: 0 ,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useCreateIndex: true
    };

    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((client) => {
      return client
    });
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise;

  return cached.conn;
}
```

`

`
this my index page

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const client = await connectToDatabase();

  const isConnected = await client.connections[0].readyState;

  return {
    props: {
      isConnected,
    },
  };
}
```

`

I tried version 5 and 6 and the addresses MONGODB_URI= mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sinema
And
mongodb://localhost:27017

I tried but nothing changed

Comment: What version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/68958221/2282634